# Is there any reason lean meats are easier to digest besides them having low fat?

Tags: nutrition

Is there any reason lean meats are easier to digest besides them having low fat? For example are the fibers that make up the tissues easier to break down in any way?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you are ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. What did you Google? Eg, is it really easier to digest?

Comment: I don't understand this question. The term "lean meat" just means meat with less fat than other meats. It doesn't mean anything more than that, so what other differences could there be?

Comment: @CareyGregory I gave an example e.g. tissue fibers, suet.

Comment: Being lean has nothing to do with being fibrous. You're treating "lean" as if it designates some type of meat or a certain species. It does not.

Comment: I voted to close as unclear what you are asking, because as Carey Gregory points out, the term "lean meat" means "low fat meat" and therefore the question as posed is circular. An equivalent question would be "Are red things easier to see besides them being red in color?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is lack of information on prior research despite requests for it

Answer (score 1):

Lean meats have less fat than fatty meats, so, yes, they are easier to digest; I'm not aware of any other thing that would make lean meat easier to digest. But this alone does not tell anything about health benefits of lean meat. For example, foods high in complex carbohydrates, which also contain dietary fiber (undigestible carbohydrates) are harder to digest than simple carbohydrates, like sugar, but are considered more beneficial for health ([kumc.edu](http://www.kumc.edu/Documents/cray/Glycemic%20Index.pdf)).

"Fiber" in meat is different than fiber in plant foods and refers to connective tissue, which is made mainly of collagen, which is a protein, which is harder to digest than the protein from muscle ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6073484/)). But it is not collagen fiber that makes meat lean; collagen fiber can be present in both lean and fatty meats.

Comment: I think this answer could be confusing to a novice because you talk about a couple different types of "fiber" that are completely unrelated; 'fibers' in meat is unrelated to the nutritional 'dietary fiber' which is not found in meat. However, the question is also circular by itself, so I also don't think this answer is good because the question should not have been answered as-is.

Comment: OK, I added a bit of explanation.

Comment: I believe I cleared the confusion in the question with my answer. I do not feel the need to be tough with everyone.

Comment: @Jan The question is moot if we don't have any idea of how the meat is prepared, collagen irreversibly turns to gelatin with extended boiling etc.

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck is right. Subject a fat cut of meat like a pork shoulder to long, slow heat and you end up with a lean end result commonly known as "pulled pork" (in the US) with all the fat rendered and all the collagen converted to gelatin. This question depends not only on how the meat is prepared but also on the cut of meat. There are cuts of beef and pork that are as lean as chicken. The question simply isn't clear and it makes unfounded assumptions.

Comment: @LangLangC, I don't find any confusion in "easier to digest." Lean meat has less fat, so it is less digestion work to be done. It seems that you worry that someone will understand that easier digestion makes lean meat healthier, but I specifically said in my answer that this is not the case. Also, the question _is not_  about low fat diet, so I don't need to address that.

Comment: @CareyGregory, the question is very clear to me: Why is lean meat easier to digest: because of lower fat content or because of fiber. There seems to be some confusion about the fiber in the question, but I cleared that in my answer. I'm aware, as you commented, that there can be more questions about lean meat, but they were not asked, so I don't need to answer them. Focused question, focused answer.

Comment: @Jan The question specifically says "besides them having low fat" so your answer doesn't address the question actually asked.